# Postgresql: How can I get 1 value from 3 different queries

Tags: postgresql

Good Morning! Let me start from the begining.
This is my query:

```
--Query 1:
select proceeding_id,operator_id,format_code,count (format_code) as E1
from legacy_formats where format_code in ('1.1.2') group by 1,2,3
UNION
--Query 2
select proceeding_id,operator_id,format_code,count (format_code) as E2
from legacy_formats where format_code in ('1.1.3') group by 1,2,3
UNION
--Query 3
select proceeding_id,operator_id,format_code,count (format_code) as E3
from legacy_formats where format_code in ('1.1.4') group by 1,2,3
```

These 3 queries gave me 4 columns results:

[image: Results]

E1= 1st result. E = 2nd result. E3= 3rd result.
And I need to get the following information:

```
E1 / ( E1 + E2 + E3)
```

So, I need to add at the end of my query another query to get this result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `SUM E1` mean?

Comment: SUM E1 means e1+e2+e3........

Comment: Then what does `SUM ( E1 + E2 + E3)` mean?

Comment: Yes, it means the addition of all e values

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please show your expected output.

Comment: OK. sorry for the inconvinient. what I'm looking for is: E1/(E1+E2+E3)...with values... 5 / (5+6+3) = 5/14 = 0.3571

Comment: it seems, updated 3 queries will fail to give shown results. Is there  4 columns or 5 columns in query result? please share correct query.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
create table tt (
    identifier varchar(20),
    e integer
 );

insert into tt values ('E1',5);
insert into tt values ('E2',6);
insert into tt values ('E3',3);

select (
    (select e from tt where identifier='E1')::float
       /
    (select sum(e) from tt where identifier in ('E1','E2','E3'))
) as ratio;

ratio
-----
0.35714285714285715
```

Comment: There is no reason for the sub queries when you can use conditional aggregation, like so: `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN identifier = 'E1' THEN e END) / SUM(CASE WHEN identifier IN ('E1','E2','E3') THEN e END) FROM table`

Comment: Lthanks a lot, let me try both answers and i'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on many aspects of your question, but assuming `myqueryresults` is the result of your query, maybe something like this would work.  I also assume that the consistent `dato id` is somehow tied to how this data is grouped.

If any of my assumptions are wrong, please feel free to clarify.

```
with myqueryresults as (
  <whatever you did to get that output>
)
select
  format_code, indentificator, e, e / sum (e) over (partition by dato_id)
from myqueryresults
```

On your sample output above, this would give you:

```
1.1.2    E1   5   0.35714285714285714286
1.1.3    E2   6   0.42857142857142857143
1.1.4    E3   3   0.21428571428571428571
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got your answer, alternately you can try this

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN identificador = 'E1' THEN e END)::numeric(5,2)/ 
SUM(CASE WHEN identificador IN ('E1','E2','E3') THEN e END))::numeric(5,4) result
FROM resultQuery
```

it gives you desired result

Comment: Good Morning...I modified my quiestion, trying to explain myself more clearly... I hope this will help you to help me. Thanks in advance